# Static factory method common for all subclasses

Tags: java, json, oop, jackson

I have many different subclasses of the same base class, and all of them should be constructed exclusively from a factory method that takes in a `JsonNode`.

Public constructors aren't convenient in my context due to extremely large (100 and more) fields. Those fields should be populated from the given `JsonNode` using `ObjectMapper`. Here is the example.

- Base class: *AbstractMessage*
- Subclasses: *MessageA, MessageB, MessageC, MessageD, ...*

Desired API:

- `MessageA a = MessageA.fromJson(json); // json of type JsonNode`
- `MessageB b = MessageB.fromJson(json); // json of type JsonNode`
- `MessageC c = MessageC.fromJson(json); // json of type JsonNode`

Method from `ObjectMapper` that does the actual conversion from `JsonNode` to object takes in a desired class argument, and this is example usage:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode json = // ...
MessageA a = jsonMapper.treeToValue(json, MessageA.class);
```

The problem occurs because, obviously, a **runtime class is needed** in order to instantiate the object of that same class. And I would like to have a static factory method in a base class to create the subclass objects, to avoid duplication etc.

I came up with the following solution:

**AbstractMessage**, base class

```
private static final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static <T extends AbstractMessage> T fromJson(JsonNode json, Class<T> cls) {
        return jsonMapper.treeToValue(json, cls);
}
```

The problem with this is, that client code needs to provide the class, and the following is also possible (which shouldn't be possible):

```
JsonNode json = // ...
MessageA a = MessageB.fromJson(json, MessageA.class);
```

... where `MessageA` is constructed through `MessageB`.

Is there a way where I could have something like this:

```
MessageA a = MessageA.fromJson(json)
```

... in the described context?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do that. Factory method must know what class to instantiate.
but why it bother you to have it like?

```
MessageA a = AbstractMessage.fromJson(json, MessageA.class);
```

> client code needs to provide the class

and what? Client code knows that it needs instance of `MessageA` class and why do not provide its class?

as example in slf4j logger framework:
`org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);`
 does anybody complain about it?

Comment: Like I said, the problem is that it's wrong to be able to do something like: 'MessageA a = MessageB.fromJson(json, MessageA.class)'. It would be like 'Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class, Logger.class)'. Where you have to give in the argument of the same class that is calling it (or even worse: some other subclass, like MessageB)